# Data truncated when trying to import CSV file

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, geoip

Hi here is my load statement:

```
load data local infile 'C:/GeoIPCountryWhois.csv' into table geolocation fields terminated by ','
  enclosed by '"'
  lines terminated by '\n';


30 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s):
1265 Data truncated for column 'cn' at row 30
Records: 30  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 1



CREATE TABLE `geolocation` (
  `start_ip` char(15) NOT NULL,
  `end_ip` char(15) NOT NULL,
  `start` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `end` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `cc` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `cn` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I found that the problem is most likely the line below because of the comma in Korea it things that a new field starts.

1.11.0.0,1.11.255.255,17498112,17563647,KR,"Korea, Republic of"

I can remove all the commas but can I change the load statement somehow?

Comment: Why is only one field enclosed by quotes?

Comment: not sure from what I can see only the fields in cn that have a comma in the text are enclosed with quotes nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY` instead of `ENCLOSED BY`.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Adding OPTIONALLY to the statement allows your CSV to be in its current form. Without the OPTIONALLY keyword, it is expected that every value will have quotations around it.

Comment: thanks for the answer, still failing though last row is  '1.11.0.0', '1.11.255.255', '17498112', '17563647', 'KR', '"Korea, Republic of"
1.12.0.0,1.15.255.255,175636'

Comment: Did you add those single quotes? They shouldn't be necessary with using the OPTIONALLY keyword. Take a look at the link I posted and find the ENCLOSED BY keyword on the page. When it goes into the OPTIONALLY option, there's an example that is very similar to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' with the combination of OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My data in mysql is ok, right now. 
what I change:

in file **GeoIPCountryWhois** - i used in excel CTRL+H to remove "**,**" from names like "Korea, Republic of" --> "Republic of Korea". and also i removed all **"**

i have to change in mysql

`start` **bigint**(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `end` **bigint**(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
because was problem from "128.0.0.0" in tables "start" and "end" (this same max int size to end of this tables - **duplicates**)

importing csv from phpmyadmin : 
(if you need translate, tell me..)

[image]